# Why DoctrineModule Cli steps in ZF2 app's command line requests?

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, command-line-interface

I'm trying to create a console-aware module for my zf2 app under the **Cli** namespace. I just created the module directory with a simple controller, module configuration file and Module.php.

Problem is when i call "php public/index.php" on command line, i'm getting DoctrineModule's default Cli output after my app's console banner like below:

```
➜  myapp git:(master) ✗ php public/index.php
--- This is app banner ---

----------------------------------------------
DoctrineModule
----------------------------------------------

DoctrineModule Command Line Interface version 0.8.0

Usage:
  [options] command [arguments]
... bla bla ...
```

module/Cli/config/module.config.php:

```
return array(
    'console' => array(
        'router' => array(
            'routes' => array(
                'testroute' => array(
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '/',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller'    => 'Cli\Controller\Index',
                            'action'        => 'index'
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ),
);
```

Content of module/Cli/Module.php:

```
<?php
namespace Cli;

use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ConsoleBannerProviderInterface;
use Zend\Console\Adapter\AdapterInterface as Console;
use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\AutoloaderProviderInterface;

class Module implements AutoloaderProviderInterface, ConsoleBannerProviderInterface
{
    public function getConsoleBanner(Console $console){
        return "--- This is app banner ---\n";
    }

    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src'
                )
            )
       );
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem on my tests was: i forgott to update the "module.config.php" with the new Controller in the "controllers => invokables"  consif array -.-'

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the intricate nature of the doctrine-module. This sort of things happen when there is an error of routing. For instance, no matching route, controller not found and etc.

And by the way, the

```
return array(
    'console' => array(
        'router' => array(
            'routes' => array(
                'testroute' => array(
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '/',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller'    => 'Cli\Controller\Index',
                            'action'        => 'index'
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ),
);
```

part does not look good. While it is ok for a web-route to have "/", for console routes it is not. You should reconsider your configuration in accordance with [Console routing docs](https://packages.zendframework.com/docs/latest/manual/en/modules/zend.console.routes.html).

Comment: akond, thanks for the answer. I just tried to change `'route' => '/'` with `'route' => 'foo'` and calling the app by `php public/index.php foo` (also tried without foo `php public/index.php`) but nothing changed.

Comment: What is your composer.json content of the "require" section? I'll try to reproduce the error.

Comment: Same problem over here!

Comment: @foozy, is there any solution for the descriped error? i just sit on the same problem right now :-/